# Can I recover a db password?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql, database, password

For our project in GCP, the app has a production Postgres db instance, we don't have the current password, therefore we can't access the db other than through the app. If we change the password, then we can access the db let's say using PGadmin but the app becomes inaccessible. We don't know where in the code that was deployed the password is. Is there any way to recover this password? or where in the code of the deployed app in GCP can be found?

Comment: What type of app? Specifically, what programming language, what frameworks (if any)?

Comment: Is this Google Cloud "hosted/managed" Postgres, or is it Postgres running on a VM that you have shell access for?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not store passwords, so no, you cannot recover a password via the database.